# Parsing emails with Python3

Tags: email, python, parser

I once parsed emails with Python2 some years ago.

It was hell.

Now I need to do it again. This time with Python3.

I am unsure whether to use the standard library or a third party library.

Can someone give me an advice?

Comment: I have my own problems with python's email parser, but I'm curious: Why was it hell for you?

Comment: (Also, this question might get more responses on stackoverflow.)

Comment: @ʇsәɹoɈ yes, this question would get more responses on stackoverflow. I know. What should I do? Several question on StackO got closed because I asked for a library. My point of view: Close softwarerecs, allow softwarerec questions on StackO.

Comment: @ʇsәɹoɈ what was hell? The unicode handling when parsing mails does not work well in Python2.

Answer (score 1):

The standard [email parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) of Python is the standard Python library for parsing emails.

Some other worth mentioning are:

1. [Flanker](https://github.com/mailgun/flanker): Open source email service by Mailgun
2. [Lbgmail](http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/): Python binding for interacting with the gmail emails
3. [Pyzmail](http://www.magiksys.net/pyzmail/)

Personally, I would advise you to go with Flanker, which is a well-maintained library by people who are well versed with e-mail services.

Comment: There's [no indication](https://github.com/mailgun/flanker/issues/97) that Flanker currently works with Python 3, which was the whole point of the question.